# Cannot upload file to blob

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage, timeoutexception, azure-sdk-for-java

I am using azure sdk for java v11.0.1 to upload files to blob storage. This error comes sometimes once in a week and it creates an outage for the application
:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: The source did not signal an event for 60 seconds and has been terminated.
2023-03-21T10:30:53.721545956Z at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleTimeout$TimeoutMainObserver.run(SingleTimeout.java:123) ~[rxjava-2.2.9.jar!/:na]
2023-03-21T10:30:53.721551557Z at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectTask.call(ScheduledDirectTask.java:38) ~[rxjava-2.2.9.jar!/:na]
2023-03-21T10:30:53.721555757Z at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectTask.call(ScheduledDirectTask.java:26) ~[rxjava-2.2.9.jar!/:na]
2023-03-21T10:30:53.721559957Z at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
2023-03-21T10:30:53.721563857Z at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
```

The application works fine after a restart. What could be the issue ? I am using azure-storage-blob version 11.0.1 and spring boot version 2.1.6.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using azure sdk for java v11.0.1 to upload files to blob storage.This error comes sometimes once in a week and it creates an outage for the application.

```java
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: The source did not signal an event for 60 seconds and has been terminated.
2023-03-21T10:30:53.721545956Z at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleTimeout$TimeoutMainObserver.run(SingleTimeout.java:123) ~[rxjava-2.2.9.jar!/:na]
2023-03-21T10:30:53.721551557Z at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectTask.call(ScheduledDirectTask.java:38) ~[rxjava-2.2.9.jar!/:na]
2023-03-21T10:30:53.721555757Z at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectTask.call(ScheduledDirectTask.java:26) ~[rxjava-2.2.9.jar!/:na]
2023-03-21T10:30:53.721559957Z at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
2023-03-21T10:30:53.721563857Z at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
```

The above error message indicates that a timeout occurred while attempting to upload a file to **AZURE Storage** using the **SDK** for Java. The timeout occurred because the source did not signal an event for 60 seconds and was terminated automatically.

I have used below code to upload the **Files** to **Azure Blob Storage**.

```
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder;


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
   String  connectStr ="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<storageaccountname>;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxL132fS9qbo2NGFL/GdLuwyWiSn+AStm9symA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
   BlobServiceClient  blobServiceClient = new  BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();
   String  containerName = "<containername>";
   BlobContainerClient  containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
   String  localPath = "<localpath>;
   BlobClient  blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient("sample09.xlsx");
   blobClient.uploadFromFile(localPath);
   System.out.println("File uploaded!!!!");;
    }
}
```

You need to change the below dependency in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.azure</groupId>
<artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
<version>1.7.2</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.azure</groupId>
<artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
<version>12.21.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Once ran the above code files are uploaded to **Azure Container** successfully.

[image]

Comment: So does it mean it is a bug in azure sdk for java v11? I need to update the version to v12?

Comment: Timeouts can occur for a variety of reasons, such as network latency, server issues, or application load, upgrading to the latest version of the Azure SDK for Java v12 and check the result.